# Windows Phone app exception: System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have a windows phone app which works fine in the emulator and on my test device (Lumia 520), but when published to the store it appears everyone is having issues with it. In my crash logs I see lots of the same error:

```
Problem Function: MS.Internal.XcpImports.TileHostV2_SetNativeContentProvider
Exception Type: System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException

Stack Trace:
"Frame    Image                         Function                                                      Offset        
0        system_windows_ni             MS.Internal.XcpImports.CheckHResult                           0x001c1f04    
1        system_windows_ni             MS.Internal.XcpImports.TileHostV2_SetNativeContentProvider    0x00000054    
2        system_windows_ni             MS.Internal.TileHostV2.BindToAgWebBrowserControl              0x00000028    
3        microsoft_phone_interop_ni    Microsoft.Phone.Controls.WebBrowserInterop..ctor              0x0000008e"
```

The problem is, this doesn't give me a great deal to go on. It doesn't appear to be related to pretty much anything in my code that I can relate to. I can see the WebBrowser component seems to be having an issue in its constructor maybe, but how can I possibly resolve that (if it is the cause)?

Has anyone seen this error before or have any idea how to diagnose it?

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked that whatever page is using the WebBrowser control is working properly?

Comment: Thats the irony though, the app doesnt use the webbrowser component...It used SyndicationService to parse RSS, using admob for ads, the in built media player and IAP

Comment: There you go, though - my best guess is the AdMob control is acting up. Is it a fatal crash that you're encountering?

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have set the **ID_CAP_NETWORKING** capability in the WMAppManifest.xml file.

Apparently MS.Internal.XcpImports.TileHostV2_SetNativeContentProvider needs it to download map tiles when executed on non-development devices.

Comment: Yes, I have the networking capability set in the manifest file. I have networking, webbrowsercomponent, identity_user & identity_device set